# include() and flatpages confusion

Tags: django, include, django-urls, django-flatpages

I'm following ***Apress: Practical Django Projects*** and I've come across something that confuses me a little.

When I set up my url.py to point to flatpages it works fine if I do this:

```
...
(r'', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')),
...
```

But it doesn't work If I do this:

```
from django.contrib import flatpages
...
(r'', include(flatpages.urls)),
...
```

It tells me that:

> 'module' object has no attribute
>   'urls'

My knowledge of both Django and Python is pretty limited, so this may be really obvious, but it would be nice to understand what's going on :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs the `urlpatterns` variable from the other module.  So try:

```
from django.contrib import flatpages
...
(r'', include(flatpages.urls.urlpatterns)),
...
```

This is inline with the example in the django docs [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs).

## Edit:

I found the issue.  There is something messing up the imports from `django.contrib`, I am still looking into that.  Change your import to `from django.contrib.flatpages import urls`.

So your code will be:

```
from django.contrib.flatpages import urls
...
(r'', include(urls.urlpatterns)),
...
```

Comment: However the error @Acorn is getting is that `flatpages` does not have `urls` as an attribute so it won't be able to get that far, and we have not yet managed to pass anything to the `include` function yet, due to that error.

Comment: Also, here's a link to the specific section of the django docs relating to passing objects to include instead of strings, although it doesn't really solve this question: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/urls/#passing-callable-objects-instead-of-strings

Comment: Interesting, thanks for taking a poke around! I'm still interested in *why* it needs urlpatterns rather than just urls (as with admin), and also why the imports are behaving the way they are (ie. not working) :)

Comment: If you look in the code you will see that admin points to a urls property (not module) that actually does return a urlpatterns object. Its under `django/contrib/admin/sites.py` line 242 if you are interested.